# Objective C(iphone) Variables changing inside Method Call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I am running an ARC project and I've noticed something that is messing up my project. 
In the following block of code,

```
- (void)didTapSuggestionButton:(id)sender {
//[_buttonDelegate suggestionButtonPressed:[sender currentTitle]];
//NSLog(@"current title is %@",[sender currentTitle]);
}
```

In the break point on the first line I am seeing the following in the debugging console.

> self  freeFormAutoCompleteScroller *const 0x0000ace9
>
> UIScrollView  UIScrollView
>
> suggestionButtons NSMutableArray *    0x6e65006e
>
> _buttonDelegate   objc_object *   0x00646564
>
> isa   objc_class *    0x00000008
>
> sender    id  0x06d7f3f0 [0]  id

---

However in the second line I see:

> self  freeFormAutoCompleteScroller *const 0x06d7f3f0
>
> UIScrollView  UIScrollView     suggestionButtons  NSMutableArray
>   * 0x00000000
>
> _buttonDelegate   objc_object *   0x00000000
>
> isa   objc_class *     sender id  0x06babf30 [0]  id

---

"Self" started referencing another memory address? Even when I didn't do anything? What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the code is being called on another thread simultaneously, check the call stack.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be, if I accidentally overlaid buttons on top of each other, I would be seeing the method call 2 or more times at the same time? Or would they immediately replace each other so I can't tell?

Comment: whoa I think you might have pointed out something important, Let me look into it a bit more

Comment: hmmm I don't think that's it...this is ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you write

```
NSLog(@"current title is %@",[sender currentTitle]);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

coolio,

Many of the values in your first dump are uninitialized. For example:

```
self freeFormAutoCompleteScroller *const 0x0000ace9
```

`self` can never be odd.

Here is an extremely unlikely address for a class object:

```
isa objc_class * 0x00000008
```

I suspect that you are somehow not `retain`ing the object that is the `target` of the button press. In other words, you are trying to execute random memory. Your problem is not in this method.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If it's called by a UIButton try modify the (id)sender to "(UIButton *)sender"